# Treeview - highlighting multiple items

Tags: treeview, powerbuilder

In Powerbuilder, Does anyone here know how am i going to highlights multiple items on a treeview? Selecteditem function is not doing that. Im looking for a behavior just what Selectedrow id doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this myself but there is an example on [CodeXchange](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1058501) (look for Multi-select TreeView Control).

I think the treeview style datawindow might be easier to do this with.

If not, I found this on the newsgroup, don't know if it helps:

> The following script in the
>   selectionchanged event will implement
>   a *very* basic multiselect in the
>   treeview:
>
> ```
> treeviewitem ltvi_item
>
> if KeyDown(KeyControl!) then
>   This.GetItem(oldhandle, ltvi_Item)
>   ltvi_Item.Selected = True
>   This.SetItem(oldhandle, ltvi_Item)
> end if
> ```
>
> A problem is deselecting the
>   previously selected items. You would
>   have to scan through ALL items do look
>   for the selected ones (once the user
>   clicks an item without holding down
>   the control key)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/powersoft.public.powerbuilder.objects/B2ulHBrSnrs/itwhNBjlyOoJ

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this is to use the CheckBoxes attribute on the treeview, then check the treeviewitem's StatePicture (Unchecked = 1, Checked = 2).

Good luck,

Terry.