# Treeview checkboxes (How to I get the checked value?)

Tags: checkbox, treeview, powerbuilder

I got problem on how to get value from checkbox in TreeviewItem. in link below, Terry [has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6257005/317266) to use this method,

> (One approach to this is to use the CheckBoxes attribute on the treeview, then check the treeviewitem's StatePicture (Unchecked = 1, Checked = 2))

but I still don't know how to used it. I don't know either I need to declare the value(1,2) to StatePicture or the value will automatically set when I checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes its possible . You can do this by little code. First you need to create two structures.

type os_point from structure
        long                l_x
        long                l_y
end type

type os_tvhittestinfo from structure
        os_point        str_pt
        long                l_flags
        long                l_hitem
end type

### Then Declare these Instance Variables

//Instance variables
Public:
Constant uint TVM_HITTEST = 4369
Constant uint TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON = 64

Protected:
Boolean        ib_stateclick = FALSE
Boolean        ib_stateclickin = FALSE
Long           il_handle

### Then you need to declare the Local External Function

//Local external function
FUNCTION long HitMsg( long hWindow, uint uMsg, long wParam,  REF OS_TVHITTESTINFO lParam ) LIBRARY "user32.dll"  ALIAS FOR SendMessageA

### On Treeview Control Mouse Move Event Write this Code

//Treeview mousemove event
OS_TVHITTESTINFO        lstr_tvhittest

il_handle = Handle(THIS)

// Get Information on whether the State Icon has been clicked.
lstr_tvhittest.str_pt.l_x = UnitsToPixels( xpos, XUnitsToPixels! )
lstr_tvhittest.str_pt.l_y = UnitsToPixels( ypos, YUnitsToPixels! )

// Send message to retrieve handle to item pointed by mouse.
HitMsg( il_handle, TVM_HITTEST, 0, lstr_tvhittest )

// Set the flag if we are over a state checkbox.
IF lstr_tvhittest.l_hItem <> 0 THEN
        ib_stateclick = ( lstr_tvhittest.l_flags = TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON )
END IF

### Then on Treeview Clicked Event Write the following code

//Treeview clicked event
TreeviewItem l_tviold
this.GetItem(handle, l_tviold)

IF ib_stateclick THEN 
    If l_tviold.StatePictureIndex=1 Then 
 
        //Check Box Checked
        Messagebox('','Check Box Checked on '+String(handle))
    Else
        //Check Box Un-Checked
        Messagebox('','Check Box Un-Checked on '+String(handle))
    End if 
END IF

---

Done. information gathered from 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sybase.public.powerbuilder.general/YOKf5OwjKI0

Regards
Raj